# Decoding a Time and Date Format

Tags: date, datetime

The Olympus webserver on my camera returns dates the I cannot decode to a human readable format.

I have a couple of values to work with.

- 17822 is supposed to be 30.12.2014
- 17953 is supposed to be 01.01.2015 (dd mm yyyy)
- 17954 is supposed to be 02.01.2015

So I assumed this was just the number of days since xxx and it turns out this is 05.11.1965, so I guess this is wrong.

Also the time is an integer value as well.

- 38405 is 18:48
- 27032 is 13:12
- 27138 is 13:16

The right values are UTC+1

Maybe somebody has an idea how to decode these two formats.

Comment: Now @Jasen has figured it out, would you like an implementation in some language?

Comment: @Jasen: Thank you, I believe this is it. At least I got the date converted probably. I will update my post when everything is working.

Comment: @Spacedman: The datetime is stored in ASCII format (already human readable) according to the EXIF standard documentation.

Comment: UTC+1 has no effect dos timestamps don't respond to timezones they just store the local time.

Comment: since it;s a web server in addition to the EXIF data there ma also be a timestamp in the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are DOS timestamps

dos timestamps are a bitfield format with the parts of the date and time encoded into adjacent bits in the number, here are some worked examples.

```
number  hex     binary
17822 0x459E = 0010 0101 1001 1110
               YYYY YYYM MMMD DDDD                  

Y=001 0010 = 34 ( add 1980 to get 2014) 
M=1100     = 12
D=1 1110   = 30

17953 0x4621 = 0010 0110 0010 0001
Y=001 0011   = 35 (2015)
M=0001       = 1
D=0 0001     = 1

17954  0x4622 = 0010 0110 0010 0010
Y=001 0011   = 35 (2015) 
M=0001       = 1
D=0 0010     = 2
```

and the times are simiilar

```
38405 = 0x9605 = 1001 0110 0000 0101
                 HHHH HMMM MMMS SSSS
H= 1 0010 = 18
M=11 0000 = 48
S= 0 0101 = 5 (double it to get 10)
```

Comment: "two seconds should be precise enough for everyone" PHP implementation here: http://proger.i-forge.net/MS-DOS_date_and_time_format/OFz - apparently zip archive files use this encoding...